# Monitor other container with telegraf (TIG stack)

Tags: docker, monitoring, influxdb, grafana, telegraf

I would like to monitor my docker containers with a TIG (Telegraf, InfluxDB and Grafana) stack running in containers too.

I would like my architecture to be like this:

[image]

I'm using [this stack](https://github.com/matisku/tig-stack) for TIG, but I'm open to any idea.

Do you have any idea how I could achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than that you should point out something like this:

[image]

In here you would only need to create base Docker Image that have the Telegraf agent installed and how to connect to InfluxDB, and the plugins selection on how to collect information from your Containers. From that point everything should be trivial.

Comment: Well I would have liked to not have to put Telegraf on every container but I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: Depending on what you want to monitor, you would need it in many use cases. One that comes to my mind that you can avoid it (in linux at least) is collecting logs from application, and if you implement a SysLog writer that writes log to an externel SysLog server (external container) you might accomplish what you are looking at. Also, to monitor "some" metrics from the outside I would recommend cAdvisor, it has InfluxDB as a native storage output and it can be containerzed to collect metrics from the outside.

Comment: I forgot to say, taking logs metrics from syslog with telegraf is rather trivial.

Comment: Well thank you very much. I wanted to use cAdvisor at first but it looks like my superior really likes Telegraf. But I'll try as you said, send syslog to a Telegraf container.  
Thank you again.

Comment: @KillianC. Let me know if that approach fits you to rephrase my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Telegraf [docker input plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/docker). If you do not need to monitor something complex this may be what you need. A single Telegraf instance on a host. No need to build it in inside a docker image.

Comment: Yes that's what I did finally and it's working great, thank you

Comment: What about monitoring disk space of other containers and of the host?